# GP Service analyser gives error 00068: broken project data source

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, publishing

I'm trying to publish a GP result to both my live and dev servers.

I ran the tool, clicked on the result and published to the live server without a problem. Then I clicked on the same result and tried to publish to the dev server, but the analyser complains about a broken project data source. The path it gives in the error message (C:\Users\jpm\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.3\Staging\arcgis on xxxx_live_6080 (admin)\0\v101\xxxx.sde) contains the address of the live server, so it's not surprising that it does not exist, as the Staging folder was cleared out after the tool successfully published.

Are we supposed to run the tool again to publish it to a different server?

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you have to rerun the tool, you have to restart ArcMap. It must cache the server path somewhere and will only change to a different server if you turn it off and on again.